# Modifying a directive to 'watch' a ctrl property?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive which checks if they click submit on a form. If so, it adds the 'submitted' class. This allows me to style the form inputs as red only when they have submitted a form (I hate having it red in real-time as they're typing).

```
'use strict';


app.directive('formSubmitted', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'form',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$submitted = false;
      element.on('submit', function() {
        scope.$apply(function() {
          ctrl.$submitted = true;
          element.addClass('submitted');
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

The problem is 'resetting' a form once it has been submitted successfully... I need to remove the `submitted` class from inside the controller. I have tried a lot of ways to do this without success... as in this pseudo-code...

`angular.element($scope.myForm).removeClass('submitted');`

What I am thinking is instead of doing that from the controller (which doesn't work anyway), that I try to make the 'submitted' class mirror the $submitted property on `ctrl`... This way I could do...

`$scope.myForm.$submitted = false` and the class would update appropriately.

I have no idea even where to begin with though, and googling isn't helping...

Thanks!

Comment: Have you sorted that out? Please accept one of the answer or let us know if you still need help. rgds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ng-class directive:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-class="{submitted: $submitted}">
```

See the doc here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Within the controller handling the form submission, you certainly have a submit function:

```
$scope.submit = function (form) {
    $scope.$submitted = true;
    if (form.$invalid) {
        return;
    }

    // Actually send data to backend, eventually receiving a promise
    promiseFormBackend = MyService.sendForm();
    promiseFromBackend.then(function () {
        $scope.$submitted = false: // resetting the form class
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach I have used in situations like this is leveraging the Angular [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) directive and binding to a property on the controller that maintains whether the state is submitted or not.  Something like so:

```
<button ng-click="isSubmitted = !isSubmitted">Submit</button>
<form ng-class="{submitted: isSubmitted}">

</form>
```

Comment: Interesting.. I have modified my directive to use `scope.submitted` instead of `ctrl.$submitted`. Can you help me understand the difference? The documentation doesn't even mention a 4th argument... (I found this directive online)

Comment: In the Angular [compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) documentation, see the section on the link function for what the 4th argument is (directive controller).  Keep in mind the suggestion I posted does not use any custom directives.